# How to pass variables to layout?

Tags: php, yii

I know how to pass variable from controller into a view:

```
$this->render('view_name', array('variable_name'=>'variable_value'));
```

however I'd like to pass some variables to layout. The only connection between controller and layout seems to be the public $layout attribute in controller class, like this:

```
public $layout='//layouts/column2';
```

However, I do not see a way to pass a variable to it?

Comment: the same way that you set the pageTitle in the layout...

Comment: your controller has a property pageTitle. it is used in your main layout file. you can set it in your view. To set a property or array of properties in your layout, simply add them to your controller class, then use them in your layout

Answer (score -2, accepted):

From your controller you can do something like this:

```
$this->render('/mail/registration',array('url'=>$url, 'description'=>'some description'));
```

and access the variables from your view like this:

```
<h3><?php echo $url; ?></h3>
```

and here is your answer; you can access these same variables from the layout like this:

```
<h3><?php echo $data['url']; ?></h3>
```

Comment: Just tried in Yii2.0. $data is undefined in the layout

Comment: This is the procedure to pass variable to `view` not `layout`

Answer (score 15):

Alternatively, you could add a property in the Controller such as

```
class SiteController extends CController {

    public $myvar;
//...
```

And then output it in the layout (//layouts/column2)

```
echo isset($this->myvar) ? $this->myvar : '';
```

Comment: Good point, guess I was thinking he didn't want to modify the controller class, but that would be the way to go if he did. Even better, if you are already using the "Controller.php" component, you can make your modifications there and it will be available to any of your controllers. I guess if you wanted to get really fancy, you could override the render method with additional attributes :)

Comment: @Petra Barus: New on Yii here. On your example, how will layout know that `$this->myvar` is the one of that specific controller ?

Comment: @MEM it doesn't have a clue. Basically the view will be executed by a Controller, and the object `$this` in the view will refer the Controller executing it. So, in my script, the view will just check whether the Controller has a public field named `myvar`. If it has, the view will echo it, otherwise it won't. Actually it's kind of bad example since there is no way the view will know who's gonna execute it. Usually I use a phpDoc just for reminding myself `/* @var $this SiteController */`.

Comment: @Mem **correction**: alternatively you can just get the controller's id `$this->id` in the view file.

Comment: In Yii2, create the Controller property as above, but in the layout use `Yii::$app->controller->myvar`

Comment: Also in Yii2, you can use $this->context->myvar, as $this in a view refers to the view, and $this->conext refers to the view's controller

Answer (score 7):

It doesn't really seem to be set up to do that easily from what I can tell, so if you are relying on it to pass a lot of data, you might want to think of a different way to set up your application.

A couple ways that you could do it are to use the Yii params via

```
Yii::app()->params['myvar'] = $mixed;
```

which you can set in the controller and access in the layout. Otherwise you can use regular PHP global vars, with all the issues that approach entails.

In your controller you would do something like:

```
global $testvar;
$testvar = 'hello';
```

and in the layout:

```
echo $GLOBALS['testvar'];
```

(Even if it's not in a function, you still need to retrieve it via GLOBALS.)

You could pass an object this way for more structured data, but you are still using a global var. Another, possibly even less desirable method, would be via a session var, e.g., `Yii::app()->session['myvar']` or a Yii "[flash message](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/21/how-to-work-with-flash-messages/)".

Answer (score 4):

in controller pass the variable, then in VIEW (not layout yet)
create

```
$this->params['myvar'] = 'hello';
```

Now in layout you can access whole array with just

```
echo $this->params['myvar'];
```

Hope this helps you.

Comment: This is the cleanest way to do it in Yii2 and should be the accepted answer.

Comment: The question was asked in 2011 which means it was about Yii1 because Yii2 did not exist at that time.

Answer (score 0):

After sets of debugging in Yii2 I found out that the only variables (excluding global variables) that are accessible inside of a layout file are **_file_** (path to current layout file) and **_params_** (an array containing variable **content** that is a HTML output bufferized from a file passed for rendering from a controller).
Except answers provided by *@ldg* (which I consider as most useful and informative, but resource spending) and *@Petra Barus*.
I also came out with a good solution of dividing layout into explicit files and calling them inside of a rendered file:

```
echo $this->renderPhpFile(Yii::getAlias('@app/views/layouts/somelayout.php'), [
    'var' => $variableThatIsAccessibleInRenderedFile,
]);
```