# Yii dataProvider theme main.php

Tags: php, yii, dataprovider, yii-routing, zii-widgets

In my SiteController.php

```
public function actionIndex()
{
    // renders the view file 'protected/views/site/index.php'
    // using the default layout 'protected/views/layouts/main.php'
    //$this->render('index');

    $dataProviderUser=new CActiveDataProvider('User',array(
                'pagination'=>array(
                    'pageSize'=>20,
                ),
            ));
    $dataProviderDomain = new CActiveDataProvider('Domain');

    $this->render('index',array(
    'dataProvider1'=>$dataProviderUser,
    'dataProvider2'=>$dataProviderDomain
    ));
}
```

In my themes/k/views/layout/main.php

```
        <?php 
        if(!Yii::app()->user->isGuest)
        {
        $this->widget('zii.widgets.CListView', array(
            'dataProvider'=>$dataProvider2,
            'itemView'=>'_view',));
        ?>
```

This error appears: **Undefined variable: dataProvider2**

If i do this in my main.php:

```
<?php 
        $dataProvider2 = new CActiveDataProvider('Domain');
        if(!Yii::app()->user->isGuest)
        {
        $this->widget('zii.widgets.CListView', array(
            'dataProvider'=>$dataProvider2,
            'itemView'=>'_view',));
        ?>
```

That works fine so far. But if I go to the User Profil:

```
/user/view/id/5
```

**Property "Domain.username" is not defined.**

So in my User _view.php Yii seems to take the Domain Dataprovider.

**How do I past those dataProviders to my layout main.php file?**
The SiteController.php doesn't seem to do that right.

Would be very nice, if someone has an idea here.
Thanks in advanced.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to pass variables to layout?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7058410/how-to-pass-variables-to-layout)

Comment: tried that out. It doesnt work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Variables that you have defined in your controller action are only available to immediate view files that are being used to render a view. They are not available to layouts. However, layouts will be able to use public methods and properties of the controller. So, if you want to pass a variable to your layout you need to declare it as a property of the controller. There are two ways of doing this.

Firstly, you can just create a public variable.

```
Class YourController extends CController{

public $dataProvider2;

public function actionIndex(){
// renders the view file 'protected/views/site/index.php'
    // using the default layout 'protected/views/layouts/main.php'
    //$this->render('index');

    $dataProviderUser=new CActiveDataProvider('User',array(
                'pagination'=>array(
                    'pageSize'=>20,
                ),
            ));
    $dataProviderDomain = new CActiveDataProvider('Domain');

//Added new line here
$this->dataProvider2 = $dataProviderDomain;
    $this->render('index',array(
    'dataProvider1'=>$dataProviderUser,
    'dataProvider2'=>$dataProviderDomain
    ));
}

}
```

$this->dataProvider is now available in your view file, but don't foorget to check that it exists before using it.

The other method is to use the magic getter method from Yii.

In your model, describe a method like this;

```
public function getdataProvider2(){
return $this->_dataProvider2;
}
```

and you'll need a property;

```
private $_dataProvider2;
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the solution. Now it works with $this->dataProvider2 in the main.php. But if I click on User Profil, it tells me that dataProvider2 is empty. I also had to add dataProvider2 to my UserController. So it seems like those controllers are all using the same variable but with different use. I dont realy get it.

Comment: It's a matter of context. When you're in the layout, $this refers to the controller that is calling the layout. So if $this->dataProvider2 is not defined in that controller, then the layout won't be able to access it.

Comment: So can I do something like DomainController.dataProvider2, so that it always takes the right Controller?

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean @Konter. When you're in a view file, or a layout file, there is only one controller handling that file. You can't refer to a property of a different controller if that's what you mean. If dataProvider1 and dataProvider2 are going to be variables that are used across all your controllers then you may be better off creating a class that extends CController and provides these variables, then having your other controllers extend this class.