# Passing Variables from controller to layout, how to avoid this - yii?

Tags: php, css, layout, yii

Recently, I've been trying to add a table of data to the left hand-side of my website. I've done so succesfully by creating a new lay-out (called column3.php). I render it from my controller and it looks like this

```
<?php $this->beginContent('//layouts/main'); ?>
  <div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="span3">

        <table class="table list_summary table-bordered">
<form action="<?php echo Yii::app()->createUrl('recipient/processpayment', array('id'=>$id)) ?>" method="post" >
    <tr class="primary"><td> <h4>List Summary </h4> </td></tr>
    <tr ><td>
        &nbsp;&nbsp;<?php echo $numrecipients ; ?> Recipient(s)
    </td></tr>

    <tr ><td>
        &nbsp;&nbsp;Total Due: &nbsp;<?php echo $totaldue ?> Rwf
    </td></tr>

   <tr> <td>  

        <h4> Mobile Money Accounts: </h4> 
        <?php 
        /* 
            foreach($accounts as $account)
            {
                echo $account->name; ?>:&nbsp; <?php echo $account->balance; ?> Rwf<br> <?php  
            } 
            */      
        ?>  

    </td> </tr>

    <tr> <td> 
        <button class="btn btn-block btn-primary " type="submit">Pay Now</button>  </td> </tr> 
    </td></tr>
</form>
```

```
    </div><!-- sidebar span3 -->
    <div class="span9">
    <div class="main">
        <?php echo $content; ?>
    </div><!-- content -->
    </div>
</div>
<?php $this->endContent();  ?>
```

Now, I've run into the problem that I need to now pass data into this table. I've looked around at how to pass variables to the layout from the controller - and the answers all include using global variables (Which I really would like to avoid). [How to pass variables to layout?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7058410/how-to-pass-variables-to-layout)  I have to think that this issue is arising because of a design flaw - perhaps this table should not be in its own default lay-out. Perhaps the table should be a widget? Previously, I had issues having the table be placed on the left side - which I fixed by placing the table in a new lay-out

Comment: You should use a service which gets the data for you. You can call this service from your view. Or you can use a widget for this which does everything including the view rendering.

Comment: Read the link you supplied again. The answer which suggested use of 'public $myvar;' is workable. $myvar is local to the controller, and is not global.

Comment: Chris what do you mean by "a service" to the get the data for me. I've looked around for a service, and right now all I'm finding with yii is service in the context of a client-service